# Intellij: move variables at method start

Tags: java, variables, intellij-idea, declaration

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate for working with Java.

There are so many useful functions, but there is one that could be very good for me and that I can't find...

Sometimes I use variables without previously declaring them (at first time). Then, I use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> functionality on the undeclared variables to open menu and select the option for automatically declaring. Sometimes it's just more rapid.

It works good, the problem is that the variable is automatically declared next the line where is used. Now, I want a function in IntelliJ that automatically moves all the declarations at the start of the methods where they are. Does it exists? Or how can I implement it?

Comment: why do you want to move variable  declarations to the method start. Usually local variable visibility scope should be as small as it is possible.

Comment: Because it could be a necessity in various situations: consider a cycle or a variable that I want to use in other places.

Comment: Is this really always the best solution? you will have all your variables in same scope, and I don't think that it's something you would want...

Comment: You can create a plugin for Intellij that performs the action that you want. Just search for the Intellij plugin SDK. Don't expect a lot of other people to use it.

Comment: Functionality does not exist (as far as I know) but your request smells like personal preference as opposed to good coding practices.  Think about it and the comments from fellow programmers, it gives you a hint that what you want is not necessary a good idea (hence the reason IntelliJ might have decided to do it the way they did)

Comment: @obey I don't read the OP as saying this is *always* the best solution. There are often times when I need to move the variable declaration that IntelliJ creates and I for one would love to have something like this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feature to move all declarations to the method start (and no plans to add it, because most coding guidelines recommend declaring variables as close to the usage as possible). For situations where you're trying to access a variable which is not visible because it's declared in a too narrow scope, there's a quickfix "Bring variable into scope" which will make this specific variable accessible for this specific usage.

You can of course write a plugin to move all variables to the top; plugin development documentation can be found [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html).

Comment: "Bring variable into scope" is good but it loss ability to autocomplete the name. I think if a way to make variable to upper scope would be better. There's a very old post in jetbrains community (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206993415-How-to-give-a-local-variable-higher-local-scope), has it been implemented today?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of a built-in option, though having just auto-declared the variable you can also split the declaration and shoot that up the method:

- Start with the cursor on the variable name
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again to show the available auto-assists (also on the light bulb menu)
- Select "Split into declaration and assignment"
- This leaves the cursor on the split variable declaration, from where you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> repeatedly to move that line up the method

Comment: And in a clean code world, methods are pretty short anyway, so the line will need to be moved very few lines anyway. Although, in a clean code world, there is not more than level of indentation, too. So basically there should rarely be a need to move declarations in the first place.

Comment: I'm searching for automatic mode. Yours isn't

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you are looking for but maybe it will help you:

You can select some expression that you want extract to a variable, than press `Ctrl + Alt + V` combination, it will find all usages of this expression in your method and put it as high as it needed for all places where it is used.